# iPhone camera angle difference between iOS15 and iOS16

Tags: swift, avcapturesession, ios16, avcapturedevice, avcapture

Hi i'm working on develop iOS custom camera app.

Recently I discovered that my camera app works differently on iOS 15 and iOS 16.

On iOS 15, the video was recorded without any cropped images, and on iOS 16, it was recorded with some cropped images as if EIS(Electronic image stabilization
) was working.

My app uses iPhone 11's ultra-wide-angle camera.

I tried the code below.

```
//use iPhone11's UltraWideAngle Camera

if connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported {
                            connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .off
                        }

--> nothings changed
```

when I changed connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .off to .standard, both iOS 15 16 devices record video cropped.

What I want to know is,

-> I wonder if ISP(Image Signal Processor) forces EIS to operate when recording videos on iOS 16.

-> If not, I want to get a video that is not cropped on iOS 15 and iOS 16.

Is there any way to change the image stabilization option through the code?

Thank you and have a good Day!